# How to hide one column of dx:GridControl in PrintPreview window?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridControl which contains many columns. Now during Print/Export i want to hide one column. Whats the logic? How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In click event you can hide the column.

Each `GridView` column has the `Visible and VisibleIndex` properties. You can simply turn off the Visible property to hide a column and turn it back on to show it again.If you set this property to `-1`, a column becomes hidden as well.

```
void HideColumn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    colToHide.Visible=false;         
}
```

PrintPreview shows the same columns as the source grid. The columns to show are taken at the moment of generating a document. You can hide required columns by setting Visible to false, when calling the `CreateDocument method` of the `VisualDataNodeLink` .

Refer this link for more information https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q312869

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void PrintAllPages(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[9].Visible = false;
        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[9].Visible = false;
        // Loop through the rows and hide the cell in the first column
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
        }
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        hw.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction, "rtl");
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
            .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
        sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
        sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
        sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
        sb.Append(gridHTML);
        sb.Append("\");");
        sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
        sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
        sb.Append("printWin.print();");
        sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void PrintCurrentPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[9].Visible = false;
        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[9].Visible = false;
        // Loop through the rows and hide the cell in the first column
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            row.Cells[9].Visible = false;
        }
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        hw.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction, "rtl");
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);            
        string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
            .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");            
        sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
        sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
        sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
        sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
        sb.Append(gridHTML);
        sb.Append("\");");
        sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
        sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
        sb.Append("printWin.print();");
        sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
        GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```